# Check which type of data is coming as response using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

As I'm using Retrofit, I've designed all the POJOs and it was working flawlessly. API is designed in such a way that it will send the required data if the data is of current date or of future dates but not for past dates. In the response, I'll get a JSON response contains a combination of JSON objects and an array as a value of a JSON object and POJOs are according to that. Now if there is no record for present and future dates then I'll receive a string instead of an array and that leads to API error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING`. So what I wanna know if there is any way that I can determine - what I'm receiving an array or a string? and how to update POJO according to that to avoid that error.

JSON response when server has no data

```
{
"Result_Code": "ND",
"Result_Status": "Success",
"Result_Message": "No record found in database.",
"Result_Output": "",
"updatedDate": "20-07-2017 10:44:37"
}
```

JOSN response will be same when server has data but with one difference

```
{
 "Result_Code": "ND",
 "Result_Status": "Success",
 "Result_Message": "record found in database.",
 "Result_Output": [{multiple elements},
                   {multiple elements},
                   {multiple elements}....],
 "updatedDate": "20-07-2017 10:44:37"
 }
```

Comment: post parsing code @Ashutosh Sagar

Comment: Can you share the response for both the cases please?

Comment: It automatically parse the data as I'm using retrofit

Comment: I like to know how to morph POJOs according to different responses from API

Comment: in pojo class Result_Output store in Object and after result check isInstance of Jsonarray

Comment: POJO is designed to receive an array but when It'll receive a string instead of that leads to API error

Comment: That seems to be working. Let me test it completely then I'll get back to you

Comment: Check this way: 

if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
    JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) obj;
}

Comment: can I see your retrofit api method declaration?

Comment: check My updated solution for parsing ArrayList from response object, it might be work as you want @AshutoshSagar

Comment: I'll check it out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pojo class named `ResponseModel`

```
public class ResponseModel {
private String Result_Code;
private String Result_Status;
private String Result_Message;
private Object Result_Output;
private String updatedDate;
...
}
```

using `Object` you can morph as below

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() 
{
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Response<ResponseModel> response, Retrofit retrofit)
   {
     parseData();     //  get other data from ResponseModel Class
     if (response.getResultOutput() instanceof List<POJO>)
     {
       doSomething();
     }
      else if (response.getResultOutput() instanceof String)
     {
       doSomething();
     }
     else  //must be error object
     {
       doSomething();
     }
  }

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) 
{
 ///Handle failure
}
});
```

using `instanceof` you check desired `Object` type

Where `List<POJO>` used for multiple elements `Model`
*check updated solution for parsing ArrayList from response object
hopefully it might be work as you want

Comment: Works like charm Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know how to convert the object to my POJO list?

Comment: are you using any library for parsing object? e.g Gson,Jakson,etc. @AshutoshSagar

Comment: @AshutoshSagar will definitely help on this can you make new question for this because of consistency in question. Post question link in comment.

Comment: thank you for asking this question and @Chirag Talsaniya thank a lot for answering it :)

Answer (score 2):

catch your json in debug mode and generate pojo class with link below. then compare your class and see difference

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
 you can try this method.

```
  try {
            callArrayPojo();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            callStringPojo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //other}
```

or you can get ResultMessage generic type

```
...
private String Result_Code;
private String Result_Status;
private T Result_Message;
...
```

Comment: I've used the same to generate POJOs but what I like to know how to morph it according to response.